# Use machine learning algorithms data structure to store information (memory)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

> DISCLAIMER : I'm pretty new to machine learning field, so forgive me
>   if my questions are somehow naive ... I already searched on Internet
>   about this topic and find nothing interesting so I am asking here ....

I wonder if a ML algorithm can be consider as a way to store data ?
There is programs that "contains" thousands of decimal of PI (e.g. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-smallest-C-program-generating-pi-without-using-the-math-library) : in some way it's a "compressed" version of the first thousands decimal of PI, right ?

In the same way ML (e.g. Deep Neural Net) seems to store information. Can we mesure how many bits is stored in a Deep Neural Net ? Can we use ML  algorithms data structure to compress information and retrieve it later (even if it's not 100% accurate) ? ...

Is there (not too technical ) papers that discuss these possibilities ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In the link you postet the complete (infinitly long) information of PI is stored, not only 1000 decimals. But it would need inifinite time/iterations to get it all ;-).

To your question: 
Like you mentioned the Learners/Classifiers store informaiton about the data you train them with. But their purpose is not to retrieve the original data back but classify/assess new data. So with caution i say: 
"no we don't simply compress data with AI algorithms and can't get the original back".

One special case would be the [K-Nearest-Neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) Algorithm.
Here you can restore the original data but thats because its not compressed, but just saved in form of hyperdimensional datapoints.

The hardest part of your question is how we could quantify the information stored in a Classifier (Deep Neural Network). If you have a [Hopfield-Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network) (wich saves and recognizes images/patterns. But is not a Deep Neural Network) you could quantify the information by counting the saved patterns and their size. For a decision tree you could count the rules (and the information gain of each rule maybe). For a neural network  you could take the number of neurons and maybe the entropy of each or all. But as you see its a really hard to answer question to specify the information stored in a trained learning algorithm.

I hope i could answer some of your questions a little bit.

Cheers